# Form tag inside script tag in vb script

Tags: html, vbscript

Can i put Form tag inside script tag? Since following code is running & gives output,

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Employment Application</h2>
        <form name="frmEmployees">
            <table border="0" width="288">
                <tr>
                    <td width="80">First Name:</td>
                    <td width="194"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80">Last Name:</td>
                    <td width="194"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

but when I put this form tag inside script tag, it just doesn't give any output.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type = "text/vbscript">
            <h2>Employment Application</h2>
            <form name="frmEmployees">
                <table border="0" width="288">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="80">First Name:</td>
                        <td width="194"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="80">Last Name:</td>
                        <td width="194"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , however if i cant put HTML tags in vbscript code, how the first code is working & second one only not giving any output.

Comment: Sorry, forget my previous answer - I mixed up vbscript and Javascript. I don't know vbscript...

Answer (score 1):

actually you can't put a `"<tag>"` inside a vbscript code, otherwise it will just give you an error of unknown command line . i think there is a way to set it using a vbs code , but the way you posted is just not working

**edit** : if what you're looking for is to add a  or edit it from a vbs script then you should declare it out of the script form then edit it from vbs {you may make it invisible then change that from a code in the script}:

```
<Script type="VBScript">
  sub button1_onclick    ' assuming that you have a button1
    frmemployees.width = 300 'to change the width
    frmemployees.height = 300 ' to change the height 
    frmemployees.InnerHTML = "String here" ' to edit the code inside of it
    ' for example to put the code you have in your example into the form do this :
    frmemployees.InnerHTML = " <table border=""0"" width=""288"">" & vblf & _
    "<tr>" & vblf & "<td width=""80"">First Name:</td>" & vblf & _
    "<td width=""194""></td>" & vblf & "</tr>" & vblf & "<tr>" & vblf & _
    "<td width=""80"">Last Name:</td>" & vblf & "<td width=""194""></td>" & vblf & _
    "</tr>" & vblf & "</table>"
    'this should be it :D 
  end sub
</script>
```

also there isn't only .width , .height and .InnerHTML, you can google it and you'll find a bunch of parameters that you can set using vbs code , hope this was what you're after

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: sorry for posting my opinion in the wrong way, but i think the question was "can i ...." so the answer is either Yes or No , as i said in my answer "No" but anyways i'll make sure to respect the laws of posting an answer in my coming posts :D

Comment: Am not getting any unknown command line error. Also the first code is giving an out & second one not.

Comment: the first should work because there is no errors, but opening <script type="text\vbscript"> tells the program that the coming is a vbs code and i guess <form> isn't one , also i think you should be putting that in a sub and then call it or have it in a window_load sub , you'll now get the error because now you called that code to run or if it works that is great !